# jQuery Unexpected Token ILLEGAL

Tags: jquery, token

For some reason, a space appears before one of the variables in my jQuery output.  I get a JS error saying unexpected token ILLEGAL.  I assume this means that there is a character somewhere that is not allowed.  The problem is that I can't figure out where it's coming from.

This is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').each(function(){

        var selectName = $(this).prop("name");
        var selectOpts = $(this).find("option");
        var selectPar = $(this).parent();

        var hiddenInput = '<input type="hidden" name="'+selectName+'" value="">';

        var menu = '<dv class="jqSelect">' + 
            '<div class="selected" id="'+selectName+'-selected"><div id="'+selectName+'-text">'+$(this).find(":selected").text()+'</div>' + 
            '<div class="caret" onclick="$(\'ul#'+selectName+'-menu\').toggle();"></div>' +
            '<ul id="'+selectName+'-menu">';

        selectOpts.each(function(){

            var optVal = $(this).prop("value");
            var optStr = $(this).text();

            if($(this).is(":selected")){

                $('#'+selectName+'-selected').text(optStr);

            }

            menu += '<li onclick="$(\'#'+selectName+'-text\').text(\''+optStr+'\');$(\'#'+selectName+'-menu\').hide();$(\'input[name="'+selectName+'"]\').prop(\'value\', \''+optVal+'\');">'+optStr+'</li>';

        });

        menu += '</ul></div>';

        selectPar.html(menu + hiddenInput);

        $('ul#'+selectName+'-menu').hide();

    });
});
```

This is where the space is happening in Chrome dev console:

```
<li onclick="$('#category_id-text').text('Tutorials');$('#category_id-menu').hide();$('input[name=" category_id"]').prop('value',="" '7');"="">Tutorials</li>
```

Comment: Easy fix; get rid of all the (generated) inline JavaScript.

Comment: Don't mix jQuery with inline event handlers

Comment: Don't have inline event handlers in the first place I'd say.

Comment: The problem is that the double quotes inside your `[name="category_id"]` are terminating the `onclick` value.

Comment: `.prop(\'value\', \'+optVal+ \');">'+optStr+'</li>';`

Answer (score 0):

You have quote issues as mentioned, but the main issue is you have inline event handlers in the generated html. That is not a good idea.

If you need to add actions to generated elements, use the

```
data-nameinlowercase="value"
```

on the elements, then assign the event handlers using

```
$("#container").on("event name","element selector",function() {
  someFunction($(this).data("nameinlowercase"));
});
```

which will handle future elements too

In your case

```
'<div class="caret" data-togglename="ul#'+selectName+'-menu"></div>'
```

and

```
$("#caretParentContainerId").on("click",".caret",function() {
  $($(this).data("togglename")).toggle();
});
```

where caretParentContainerId is the ID of the container that wraps the .caret elements

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the double quotes inside others double quotes, like this

```
<li onclick="something="something more" something else"></li>
```

If you want keep your code structure try this:

```
menu += '<li onclick="$(\'#' + selectName + '-text\').text(\'' + optStr + '\');$(\'#' + selectName + '-menu\').hide();$(\'input[name=' + selectName + ']\').prop(\'value\', \'' + optVal + '\');">' + optStr + '</li>';
```

but I think it's better you do something like this:

```
menu += '<li onclick="myFunction(' + selectName + ", " + optStr + ", " + optVal + ')">' + optStr + '</li>';
```

and create a function like this:

```
function myFunction(selectName, optStr, optVal) {
        $("#" + selectName + "-text").text(optStr);
        $("#" + selectName + "-menu").hide();
        $("input[name='" + selectName + "']").prop("value", optVal);
    }
```

With this is easier to debug and simplifly your code.